# Making List of Map from Other Component Show in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I tried to make new component for list film. But it seems error in page Home.

Here my code in component list map:

```
   import './Home.css';
import './ListFilm';
import ListFilm from './ListFilm';

function Home() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">

        <h2>The List of Films</h2>
          <div className="list film">
            <ListFilm/>

          </div>
</div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Home;
```

Here is component file named ListFilm.js :

```
    import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function ListFilm() {

    const [post, setPost] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const response = await fetch(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=9e0de5499870264659308848dbad6b2a"
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setPost(data);
          console.log(response)
          console.log(data);
        };
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    return (
<>
{post.results && post.results.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        <h3>{item.original_title}</h3>
        <img src={item.backdrop_path} alt="poster"/>
        <p>Tanggal Rilis: {item.release_date}</p>
    </div>
))}
</>
    );
  }
  
  export default ListFilm;
```

The goal is making data and image in listfilm.js showing in page Home.js. The error code in console log said that index.js:1 The above error occurred in the  component: Please help me. Thanks

Comment: can you add the error message as well ? . Also add the shape of your `post` state .

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: 'the shape of your post state ' like what?

Comment: can you add your response structure of the data which you receive from your API call

Comment: that too long :(

Comment: The error says that that your post.results is undefined and you are trying to do a map on top of undefined . You can guard your code as `post?.results?.map`

Comment: okay,, i will try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236485/discussion-between-shyam-and-firsty-ukhti-molyndi).

Comment: and oh what about image

Comment: is that right or wrong?

Comment: Were u able to fix it?

Comment: yes, but images still wont shown up. :(